# difference between order by and sort by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there any `sort by` code in `sql` which replace `order by`  in `sql` query

Comment: There is no `sort by` in SQL Server.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Hint: Search and research section.

Comment: Why do you want a replacement for `order by`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such thing as "sort by" in SQL. `ORDER BY` lets you establish the sort order of your result set.

`GROUP BY` means something entirely different. You should read about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
If you work with a SQL interface in Spark like Hive or Spark SQL, you will be able to use SORT BY or ORDER BY.
ORDER BY will work better with numbers and SORT BY with strings.
Regards.